# How does one prove if the set of all functions with a domain A and codomain B is countable or uncountable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How exactly does one prove this with the number of functions? I can't understand that. For example, with a domain of the set of all finite bit strings ({0, 1}
∗) and a codomain of {0,1}, how exactly does someone prove if this is countable or not? I can't imagine how you can make this concrete in any way.

I'm assuming this has something to with Cantor's diagonalization argument or something?

Answer (score 0):

As you suspected, you can in fact use Cantor's diagonalization argument. Here is a sketch:

*Lemma [ZFC]*. Let $A$ be infinite and let $B$ have at least two elements, then
$$
\{ f \mid f \colon A \to B \}
$$
is uncountable.

*Proof*. Fix a countable subset $\{ a_n \mid n \in \mathbb N \} \subseteq A$ (we require that $a_m = a_n \implies m=n$, i.e. there are no repititions). Fix distinct $b_0,b_1 \in B$. Suppose
$$
\{ f \mid f \colon A \to B \}
$$
where countable. Then
$$
\{ f \mid f \colon \{a_n \mid n \in \mathbb N \} \to \{b_0,b_1\} \} = \{f_n \mid n \in \mathbb N \}
$$
would be countable as well. Now define
$$
f \colon \{a_n \mid n \in \mathbb N\} \to \{b_0,b_1\}, a_n \mapsto \begin{cases} b_0 & \text{, if } f_n(a_n) = b_1, \\
b_1 & \text{, otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
Clearly $f \neq f_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ which is our desired contradiction.

Comment: Since the domain in your setting is infinite and the range has two elements, this lemma solves your question.

Comment: Using very simple heuristics you can omit choice entirely. Note that $A$ can be injectively mapped into this set. So if $A$ is uncountable, we're already one. So we only need to handle the case of $A$ being countable. In particular, no reason to add the assumption it is Dedekind-infinite.